# Random walk hitting probability

Tags: probability, markov-chains, markov-process, random-walk

If $p_i$ is the probability of hitting $i$ when starting at 0 on a simple random walk on the integers, I am struggling to understand thoroughly why $p_i=p_1^i$ due to the Markov property.

I understand heuristically, hitting $i$ is ‘like hitting 1 $i$ times’, but I would love to see a formal derivation/proof of why this is the case.

Comment: Are you aware of the strong Markov property?

Comment: Yes but I’m unsure how to apply it in this instance

Answer (score 0):

We can show this by induction: for $i=1$ this result is obvious. So suppose $p_i = p_1^i$ for some $i\ge 1$. We want to show $p_{i+1} = p_1p_i$.

Define a stopping time $\tau$ to be the first time our SRW $X$ hits $i$, formally we let $$\tau = \inf\{n\ge 1: X_n = i\}.$$
Then the event $\{\tau<\infty\}$ is precisely the event that $X$ hits $i$, so $\mathbb{P}(\tau<\infty) = p_i$.

The strong Markov property now tells us that conditional on $\{\tau<\infty\}$, $(X_{n})_{n\ge \tau}$ is independent of $(X_n)_{n\le \tau}$ given $X_\tau$. Therefore conditional on $\{\tau<\infty\}$, $(X_n)_{n\ge \tau}$ is a SRW starting from $X_\tau = i$. In particular if $Y$ is a SRW starting from $i$, $$\mathbb{P}(\exists n\ge \tau : X_n=i+1|\tau<\infty) = \mathbb{P}(\exists n\ge 0: Y_n = i+1) = p_{1}.$$
Since $X$ must hit $i$ first if it is to hit $i+1$ we have $$\begin{align*}
p_1&=\mathbb{P}(\exists n\ge \tau : X_n=i+1|\tau<\infty)\\
 &= \mathbb{P}(\exists n\ge 0: X_n=i+1|\tau<\infty)\\
& = \frac{\mathbb{P}(\exists n\ge 0: X_n=i+1,\tau <\infty)}{\mathbb{P}(\tau<\infty)}\\
&= \frac{\mathbb{P}(\exists n\ge 0: X_n=i+1)}{\mathbb{P}(\tau<\infty)}\\
&= \frac{p_{i+1}}{p_i}.
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thank you for this. Can you explain how you got to the second line in the last block where you changed from tau to 0. Also, how do we know we can apply the strong Markov property?

Comment: $X$ cannot hit $i+1$ before time $\tau$ so changing from $\tau$ to $0$ makes no difference. It's generally true that for any discrete Markov chain, the strong Markov property holds.